# SSRS vertically cascade parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012, cascade

I have an SSRS report with cascading parameters.  I'd like the parameters to cascade down vertically:

```
    Division
    State
    Office Manager
    Facility
```

[image]

The other parameters do not cascade.  Although I have the parameters cascading, because of the layout in SSRS they are not automatically cascading by default.

From the screenshot that I attached you can see that Office Manager and Facility are not populating by default.  This is because the location of the Privileging Status parameter forces the user to select it before it continues down to Office Manager and Facility.

If I try to rearrange the order of parameters in the Parameters screen, it messes up the cascading order.  To get all 4 cascading parameters to cascade by default they need to be ordered as: cat, state, officemngrname, entity.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get this to properly cascade vertically?  I'm using SSRS 2016.

Comment: Unless you stack all the parameters in a single column then I'm not sure you can do this. The order of the parameters is in reading order row by row, left to right. This order determines the order in which they are evaluated as well as where they physically appear. I have thought this is a bit of a flaw too and not sure why parameters could not have an order property which was not related to the position, but that's the way it is at the moment to my knowledge.

Comment: Does the Office Manager and Facility datasets reference the Privileging Status parameter?

Comment: @aduguid--no, they don't.  Category, State, Office Manager and Facility are all cascading parameters.  They do not reference the others.